# Total a column, divide by corresponding value

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, group-by, sum

I am using sqlite3 and I am trying to calculate the sum of each class' data out of each class' value, as a percentage.

```
Class    Data    Value
A        1       100
A        2       100
B        2       50
B        4       50
```

As an example, for A I would calculate ((1 + 2)/100) * 100.

So I would output

```
Class    Output
A        3%    
B        12%
```

So far I have come up with

```
SELECT class,
   (SELECT sum(data) / value from Table) * 100 AS "Output"
FROM Table
GROUP BY class;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation. It seems like `value`s are fixed for each `class`, in which case you can do:

```
select class, 100.0 * sum(data) / value
from mytable
group by class, value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select class, sum(data) * 100.0 / value
from t
group by class, value
```